# Use clcache with Incredibuild

Tags: c++, ccache, incredibuild

I'm trying to speed up compilation by using ClCache together with Incredibuild.

I've configured ClCache by replacing the cl.exe with the ClCache.exe.

However, when using incredibuild it tries to execute tasks on a helper, but it never uses its output.

I see CL.exe (the renamed clcached.exe) calling Python.exe callin CL_original.exe (the original cl.exe) via procesexplorer on the helper.

1. Is it possible to view the output of the cl-command executed on an Incredibuild-helper? (This would allow me to further debug the situation)
2. Did anyone succeed in configuring Clcache to work together with incredibuild?

PS: I also tried to use /MsBuild with a /p:CLToolExe pointing to ClCache, also no success.